# Mongos connection not cleared

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

We have MongoDB shard server setup with Router + Config + 2 Shard servers [MongoDB version 4.4] and accessing the mongos connections via 4 servers with PHP7.

Recently add 1 extra server(4+1=5) with PHP8 setup [Same Mongo DB version 4.4] due to upgrade and use the common PHP latest libraries.

In new server mongos connection keep on increasing up to 240 and connections not clear after complete the application process.

So when reached the mongos connection above 450 in all 5 server means mongos disconnected with below error:

### PHP Error message:

> Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx'] in

### MongoDB Error log message:

```
{
    "t":{
        "$date":"2023-10-31T08:31:32.410+00:00"
    },
    "s":"I",
    "c":"NETWORK",
    "id":23018,
    "ctx":"listener",
    "msg":"Error accepting new connection on local endpoint",
    "attr":{
        "localEndpoint":"xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx",
        "error":"Too many open files"
    }
}
```

### Mongos connection count when disconnect:

```
{
    "current":452,
    "available":367,
    "totalCreated":29913,
    "active":10,
    "exhaustIsMaster":0,
    "exhaustHello":0,
    "awaitingTopologyChanges":0
}
```

Need for connections clear after complete the application process

Comment: Do you explicitly close connections when you are done with them?

Comment: It shows deprecated error from php mongo driver when close the connections in explicitly

Comment: OH, I misread the error.  It's not complaining about too may connections, but too many files.  You might try increasing the open file limit, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/ulimit/#unix-ulimit-settings

Comment: Already we did the increase open file limit, but open connection not close after all process complete in PHP8